# Is this magnetic connector for iPhone approved by Apple?

Tags: iphone, ipad

One of the problems with iPhone/iPad cables is that they get bent and damaged. There is a smart idea floating around about a magnetic cable similar to the MacBook one. The lightning connected is attached to the iPhone and the cable gets connected to it because it magnetic

[image]

Kickstarter and indiegogo have more than one project promoting this concept.

I would love to purchase one of these cables but from a previous experience I can say that any lightning that isn't approved by Apple will cause endless problems.

[One of the projects](https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/asap-connect-the-future-of-usb-cables#/)' developer claim that his lightning is approved by Apple, below is a quote from the FAQs which I failed to understand

> Why have you not chosen to use the original lightning connector or
>   have MFi certification?
>
> Apple has not released a magnetic lightning connector, hence it is not
>   possible to apply for MFi certification and by producing a lightning
>   connector that is not MFi certified, it leaves that company open to
>   legal action by Apple. Any company claiming to have MFi magnetic
>   connectors would not be truthful as of April 2016.

**Is he saying that his cable is approved by Apple or not? What about other products?**

Comment: They're saying Apple hasn't approved any "magnetic lightning connectors" so they and their competitors are selling non-certified connectors.

Comment: @Dan so they themselves are not offering a genuine Apple approved connector?

Comment: No, it doesn't look like they are. Apple also holds patents for their Magsafe technology, which these could easily infringe upon. I wouldn't go near any of these while they're in a Kickstarter/Indiegogo phase.

Comment: @Dan would you like to put your comments as an answer?

Comment: I know this is kind of overly critical, but it's "Lightning" not "lightening".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're saying Apple hasn't approved any "magnetic lightning connectors" so they and their competitors are selling non-certified connectors.

Apple's patent [7,311,526](http://patft1.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO2&Sect2=HITOFF&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsearch-bool.html&r=1&f=G&l=50&co1=AND&d=PTXT&s1=7311526.PN.&OS=PN/7311526&RS=PN/7311526) covers their Magsafe technology, which these lightning connectors could easily infringe upon.

I wouldn't go near any of these while they're in a Kickstarter/Indiegogo phase.